# Linear Regression script not working in Python

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I tried running my Machine Learning LinearRegression code, but it is not working. Here is the code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\SVISHWANATH\Downloads\datasets\GGP_data.csv')
df["OHLC"] = (df.open+df.high+df.low+df.close)/4
df['HLC'] = (df.high+df.low+df.close)/3
df.index = df.index+1
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df.index, df.OHLC)
```

Basically, I just imported a few libraries, used the read_csv function, and called the LinearRegression() function, and this is the error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[   1    2    3 ... 1257 1258 1259].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or 
array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message, you need to give the fit method a 2D array.
df.index is a 1D array. You can do it this way:

```
reg.fit(df.index.values.reshape(-1, 1), df.OHLC)
```